# 403 forbidden for url in java but not in browser

Tags: java

I'm behind a corporate firewall, but i can paste the URL in my browser with and without my proxy settings enabled within the browser and can retrieve the data fine. I just can't within java.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
 private static String getURLToString(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    // LOG.debug("Calling URL: [" + strUrl + "]");
    String content = "";

    URLConnection connection = new URL(strUrl).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
    connection.connect();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        content += inputLine;
    }

    br.close();

    return content;
}
```

Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Response: '403: Forbidden' for url: '<url here>'
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:778)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:37)
```

Note: The '' portion is for anonymizing.

Comment: You can dump your traffic using `tcpdump` or `wireshark` and analyze difference.

Comment: @qbolt - any solution for this??

Answer (score 2):

As you are receiving a "403: Forbidden" error, it means that your Java code can reach the URL, but it lacks something that is required to access it.

In the browser, press F12 (developer/debug mode) and request the URL again. Check the headers and cookies that are being sent. Most likely you will need to add one of these for you to be able to receive the content you need.

Comment: I manually added all of them via connection.setRequestProperty() and recieved the same error.

Comment: Ditto, for me. Added every header, checked in wireshark, no change.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "User-Agent" header fixed it for me:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following headers to `URLConnection` to get past this. Found them with inspector via a refresh from the network tab.

```
conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0"); 
conn.addRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "http://dig.ccmixter.org/");
```

Comment: code view should be updated